# Curl "Could not resolve host: POST" ASP.NET Web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, curl

I created a simple ASP.NET Web service using Visual studio 2008. The Web service works fine when I use it via IE 8, but I didn't manage to consume it using curl.

Basically the "welcome page" of the Web service indicates the following example for a POST request:

Request format:

```
POST /Service1.asmx/TestService HTTP/1.1
Host: IP_ADDRESS
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length
```

Response example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

This is what I'm trying to do using the following curl command:

```
curl POST http://IP_ADDRESS/Service1.asmx/TestService  -d ""
```

But I get the following error message:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST
```

Comment: So apparently it parses `POST` as the url. Have you checked the manual of your curl implementation? Maybe you need a `-X`?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

```
curl -X POST http://IP_ADDRESS/Service1.asmx/TestService  -d ""
```

Comment: I don't get an error message with this one but I get anything displayed in my console actually, I was expecting to get something like "HTTP 200 OK"