# curl: (6) Could not resolve host: curl

Tags: curl

Getting below error initially while running the `cURL` command from execute process task (cURL as executable) using SSIS in Visual Studio.

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: curl

However, it succeeded eventually and update the record in database.

[image]

I have around 2.5 MM records that needs to updated and because of this initial error it's wasting 1-2 sec on each record.

`cURL` command is as below:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUz...." "https://scvl-api.companyname.com/api/v1/customer/100011017155"  --data "{\"addressLine1\":\"23 COURTSIDE PL\",\"city\":\"LITTLE ROCK\",\"state\":\"AR\",\"zip\":\"72210\"}"
```

When I run the same command from command prompt manually, I don't get this error at all.

Comment: check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47571701/curl-could-not-resolve-host-post-asp-net-web-service) please, may be it helps

Comment: @AbdelrahmanFarag, calling API using IP Address didn't work.

Comment: could you please try to get full error log